# Присоединить проект с github к проекту в android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-material-dialog-lib

ЮрийСПб, ответив на вопрос, посоветовал воспользоваться следующей  библиотекой: [Material Dialogs](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs)

у меня возникла проблема присоединения этого проекта. я знаю как добавить `Library Folder` или  `Jar`. проект по данной ссылке выглядит больше как проект, чем как `Library`.

как правильно добавить проект на ссылке к проекту в `Android Studio`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В файле `build.gradle` (module app) добавьте вот это как и описано на странице библиотеки:

```
dependencies {

    ...

    //materialDialogs
    compile('com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.4@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    //materialDialogs
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

Comment: ок но не надо добавлять ничего в сам проект ?

Comment: @DavidKern, эта запись в этом файле автоматом скачает нужные файлы из сети и присоединит их к проекту.